# Docker: appwrite install permission error

Tags: docker, window, appwrite

I am trying to install appwrite in my local docker, but I encounter some error

First I run this Command then

```
docker run -it --rm ^
    --volume //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ^
    --volume "%cd%"/appwrite:/usr/src/code/appwrite:rw ^
    --entrypoint="install" ^
    appwrite/appwrite:1.2.1
```

#2 show some error

```
Starting Appwrite installation...
Choose your server HTTP port: (default: 80)

Choose your server HTTPS port: (default: 443)

Choose a secret API key, make sure to make a backup of your key in a secure location (default: 'your-secret-key')

Enter your Appwrite hostname (default: 'localhost')

Enter a DNS A record hostname to serve as a CNAME for your custom domains.
You can use the same value as used for the Appwrite hostname. (default: 'localhost')


Warning: file_put_contents(/usr/src/code/appwrite/docker-compose.yml): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/src/code/app/tasks/install.php on line 203
```

#3 Error **Warning: file_put_contents(/usr/src/code/appwrite/docker-compose.yml): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/src/code/app/tasks/install.php on line 203**

first it was working, but after network failed, it through this error!

**mistakenly I run**

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

then my localhost used for Getting started, how can I remove "getting started" docker command from my machine?
or is there another problem, I missing out

can any body help me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The install command creates a folder and a couple of files, so you need to ensure you're running it in a location where you have write access. If I recall correctly, Command opens in your system32, a system folder. I suggest changing to another directory (maybe in your home folder) and running the install again (after stopping that getting started container).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best solution is manual data backup and clear installation. After data backup container removal fixed my problem

> Check this issue [for backup/restore scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75346855/how-can-i-move-my-appwrite-image-alongside-all-the-projects-to-a-seperate-comput/77027833#77027833)

[image: docker-hub]